# Angular2:RxJS Subject not responding to events

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, subject-observer

I maintain a table which is generated from array of objects in which on click on a row would give an object which contain data of that one particular row.I needed to share it with all other components no matter it is a parent,child or sibling and and hence i use Subject,similar to https://embed.plnkr.co/P8xCEwSKgcOg07pwDrlO/. The problem i face is, on click, I assume event isnot getting emitted due to which I see nothing being reflected in another component. PLease let me know where i went wrong and help resolving.My code is below:

patientlist.component.ts

```
 getPatientDetail(value)  { //value gets passed on click of row in table
        this.patientService.getPatientDetail(value);
   }
```

patient.service.ts

```
         patientdata=new Subject<Object>();
         currentdata=this.patientdata.asObservable();
          getPatientDetail(data:Object){
          console.log(data);
          this.patientdata.next(data);
          }
```

patient.component.ts

```
 constructor(private patientService: PatientService) {

   this.patientService.currentdata.subscribe(data=>{
    console.log("am here"); //even this doesn't get reflected
    this.data=data;
    console.log(this.data); //nothing here as well
    })};
```

Comment: Why are you subscribing to currentdata and not patientdata?

Comment: @Gayathri can you try using BehaviourSubject instead of Subject

Comment: Both doesn't make a difference Rahul,except for the fact that in behaviorsubject, you can set a default value which get logged when there is no data. LIke the one we discussed yesterday. If line is         patientdata=new Subject<Object>({"message":"nothing"); , if there is no data, it'll be {"message":"nothing"}. Yesterday i set it as blank {} so it displayed {}. That's it

Comment: @Carsten  I just followed the way it was done previously. Ain't sure of reason .

Comment: How did you declared provider of PatientService? Maybe you have different instances of it. You need to declare it in root Component of your `patient` and `patientlist`

Comment: Well, i actually added providers:[PatientService] in PatientListComponent and patientComponent  alone. PatientListComponent is child of patientComponent. patientComponent is child of Appcomponent. Nowhere else.

Comment: Then you need to declare it in `PatientComponent`, not in `PatientList`

Comment: @AntonLee Genius. You found out exactly where i went wrong. IT's working all well now . Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @AntonLee add an answer

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare provider of PatientService in `PatientComponent`, not in `PatientList`

Comment: i face the same issue in another hierarchy. /patient is parent. /patient/list is independent and that's sorted out. Then comes /patient/care where carecomponent is again a parent from which comes /patient/care/x, /patient/care/y which needs those data as well . Where and where not providers be given ?

Comment: If you need service in all of this components, and there is no inheritance between them, then declare in AppComponent. Or other single parent component.

Comment: data doesn't get reflected anywhere else except /patient and /patient/list