# Angular2:Sharing data between components via routes -Subject

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Consider I have 3 components.
1. PatientComponent in /patient
2.PatientListComponent in /patient/list
3.PatientCareXComponent in /patient/care/x

I used behaviorsubject in patient.service.ts to cast the data from patientlistcomponent. I face some issues:
1. Initially in /patient/list page from where data arrives, I see data visible in PatientComponent in console.logs but not PatientCareXComponent.
2. When i move to /patient page from /patient/list, the visible data also disappears.

The code is as same as [Angular2:RxJS Subject not responding to events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855728/angular2rxjs-subject-not-responding-to-events) and it is the same code in PatientComponent I have added in  PatientCareXComponent . Please favour on this.

Comment: Could you post some code here? Or develop a plunker? If you are using data bindings, in many cases you don't need a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`, you can just use a service with simple properties. I have a blog post about it here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Comment: Most of them are router-outlet @DeborahK

Comment: If you could create a small plunker example of what you are trying to do, I could provide an example of how to do it with a simple service. Otherwise you can look at my plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview